# Modify app icon in TaskManager and not in System tray

Tags: c++, winapi, icons, taskmanager

I have a program in Windows 10 that displays various icons on the system tray depending on the state of the program.

This is typically done by calling the windows api - Shell_NotifyIcon

```
Shell_NotifyIcon(NIM_MODIFY/NIM_ADD, &data);
```

The problem is that I want to show a different icon on the Task Manager. Is there a specific call I can do to solely change the icon in Task Manager?

Comment: The notification area is independent from task manager. Feel free to do what you like.

Comment: I guess my follow up would be - how do I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Task manager displays icon for executable. Which is the first icon among executable resources.

Comment: So when I do Shell_NotifyIcon, the purpose is to show different states of the program (IE a warning state or an error state icon). What I want is that functionality to still exist but then just have task manager take the default icon. I'm not sure how I would set the default icon to be the first icon and then not modify it again.

Comment: @David You will need to declare resource id of default icon to the lowest value in resource header file. Typically icon resources start from index 101. This icon will be displayed by the Expolere as well.